# Text in Rect - Pygame

Tags: python, user-interface, sdl, pygame

Do you know if I can insert text in Rect and how ?

I've created a Surface Objet and I add Text on it, I think It's not the best method.

Comment: post your code on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always veered from PyGame but from experiences with raw SDL and OpenGL, I can almost confirm you're doing the best way.

Something like:

```
Text.position = rectangle.position + rectangle.size / 2
Text.position.X = Text.position.X - text.width / 2
```

Would centre it for you too.